# Constexpr значение как non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Я пробовал сделать `static_assert` для одного конструктора сразу в `std::enable_if`, используя *msvc*.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts>
struct typelist {};

struct nothing {};

template<bool Boolean>
constexpr bool throw_assert() {
    static_assert(Boolean);
    return Boolean;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr bool contains(typelist<Ts...> = {}) {
    return (... || std::is_same_v<T, Ts>);
}

template <typename ... Ts>
struct SomeClass {

    using type_list = typelist<Ts...>;

    constexpr SomeClass(std::enable_if_t < throw_assert < contains<nothing>(type_list{}) > () > * = 0) noexcept {}
};

int main() {
    SomeClass<int, nothing>* someClass = new SomeClass<int,nothing>();
    delete someClass;
    return 0;
}
```

Но компилятор ругается, что в `throw_assert` подается не compile-time константа. (Если оставить только `contains`, то все нормально). Неужели такой трюк не будет проходить?

**PS**: Пока писал вопрос. Оказывается такое не проходит и на [clang тоже](https://godbolt.org/z/47ERLm), но gcc нормально съедает. Где правильно поведение?

Comment: clang тоже компилирует, у вас русская с в `-std=c++17`

Comment: @VTT, да, я тоже уже заметил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кому интересен обход для MSVC (Работает только на 1916 и выше), на [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-onote) 1914 не хочет собираться):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts>
struct typelist {};

struct nothing {};

template <typename Intergral>
inline constexpr bool throw_assert(Intergral = {}) {
    static_assert(Intergral::value);
    return Intergral::value;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr bool contains(typelist<Ts...> = {}) {
    return (... || std::is_same_v<T, Ts>);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
inline constexpr decltype(auto) contains_integral(typelist<Ts...> = {}) {
    return ::std::bool_constant<(... || ::std::is_same_v<T, Ts>)>{};
}

template <typename ... Ts>
struct SomeClass {

    using type_list = typelist<Ts...>;

    constexpr SomeClass(std::enable_if_t < throw_assert(contains_integral<nothing>(type_list{})) > * = 0) noexcept {}
};

int main() {
    SomeClass<int, nothing>* someClass = new SomeClass<int,nothing>();
    return 0;
}
```

PS: Правка для 1914:

```cpp
...
template <typename = std::enable_if_t < throw_assert(contains_integral<nothing>(type_list{})) >>
constexpr SomeClass() noexcept {}
```